# Read the content of a PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I need to read certain parts from a complex PDF. I searched the net and some say FPDF is good, but it cant read PDF, it can only write. Is there a lib out there which allows to get certain content of a given PDF?

If not, whats a good way to read certain parts of a given PDF?

Thanks!

Comment: how would you define 'certain parts'? By page? By coordinate location on the document? etc;

Comment: Not sure myself, I am not that familiar with PDF structure ... Illproly convert it to text before and parse that using some regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions here:

- converting your PDF file into something else before: [text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext), html.
- using a library to do so and bad news here, most of them are written in Java.

https://whatisprymas.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/lucene-how-to-index-pdf-files/
(archived [version from 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120920055456/https://whatisprymas.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/lucene-how-to-index-pdf-files/))

Comment: Is there a Widnows cmd tool for that?

Comment: Yeah, that converts pretty fast, even for complex PDFs. I guess there is no other way ... have to parse the text before.

Comment: The link is broken now - any chance for an update?

Comment: @Andreas archive.org has it. There are probably nicer tools now.

Comment: jep, we found https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser now - it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = pdf2text ('sample.pdf');
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
```

How to get “clean” text :[source code pdf2text](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/scripts/pdf2text.zip)
http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

What about that ?

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/702-PHP-Searches-pdf-documents-for-text.html

ps: I don't test this class, just read the description.

Comment: free and simple registration.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is also https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser:

```php
use Smalot\PdfParser\Parser;

$pdfParser = new Parser();
$pdf = $pdfParser->parseFile('../path/to/your.pdf');

$content = $pdf->getText()

// or if you need to maintain the paragraphs
$content = preg_replace('/\s{3,}/m', "\n\n", trim($pdf->getText()));
```